# Why does pip try to install an incompatible version of a library in a python2 virtualenv?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

Take for example, the library `more-itertools`. It has specified `python_requires = >= 3.4` to indicate that it's not compatible with prior versions.

When I try to `pip install more-itertools` in a brand new virtualenv (pip==19.2.3, setuptools==41.2.0), I get the following error:
`ERROR: Package 'more-itertools' requires a different Python: 2.7.10 not in '>=3.4'`

My question is: how do I get pip to install a prior version which is compatible? Is this possible, or do I have to pin my dependencies to the prior version?

I don't see anything in `pip install --help` that's particularly useful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK now I'm even more confused.

Trying this out on a fresh docker, it seems to work out of the box:

```
from centos:centos7

RUN yum install -y epel-release
RUN yum install -y python-pip

RUN python -m pip install -U virtualenv pip

RUN mkdir /test

WORKDIR /test

RUN virtualenv venv

ENV PATH="/test/venv/bin:$PATH"

RUN pip install more-itertools
```

this installs `more-itertools==5.0.0`

Edit: as it turns out this is a problem with the index server I'm using, which doesn't properly communicate the python_requires metadata at install time.